# At most halfway!

Tags: cipher, visual

Try to interpret this image below. Why these numbers? Give a full explanation as to why.

Let's play b!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation for how the numbers relate to the shapes

> There are pairs of triangles, squares, pentagons, and hexagons. The square and the pentagon in particular appear to be rotated. Also, the digits at the bottom appear to be restricted to early digits, so this is an inspiration to look at the number from a smaller base.
>  This ends up being pretty fruitful. 231 = 45 base 4, 330 = 90 base 5, 500 = 180 base 6, and 11110 = 120 base 3. These numbers are good factors of 360, the number of degrees in a circle. (There are other possible parsings, like 231 = 120 base 7 or 11110 = 30 base 2, but I ultimately ruled that out later on.)
>  This can be confirmed as the square (4 sides) is rotated 45 degrees and the pentagon is rotated 90 degrees. The hexagon and the triangle do not appear to be rotated, but that is because their respective rotations (180 degrees and 120 degrees) is a multiple of $360/n$ where $n$ is the number of sides it has. So this rotation will not appear to do anything.

Possible explanation for other considerations (why these particular numbers, why this ordering)

> The ordering of the numbers is chosen so that it appears to be ascending when read normally. As for why the exact numbers 45, 90, 180, and 120 are chosen (when e.g. 135, 198, ... would work), it's possible that **the numbers are chosen to be factors of 360**. As for why 18 was not chosen for the pentagon, perhaps we have to fix a certain rotation at the beginning, like counterclockwise reading from left to right. As for why a smaller rotation of the hexagon (60, 120) are not chosen, perhaps we should use the title. 198, 240, ... would be more than halfway the circle (180), which the title suggests that we don't do. So perhaps we needed a **factor of 360 that is maximal but does not go over 180 degrees**.

I can't immediately explain the ordering of the shapes, but perhaps that is arbitrary.

Comment: This is the correct reasoning and answer! well done! rot((jul V pubfr onfr3 onfr4, onfr5 naq onfr6 jnf orpnhfr gur glcr bs onfr pbeerfcbaqrq gb gur ahzore bs fvqrf bs gur bowrpg. Gevnatyr - onfr3, Fdhner - onfr4, cragntba - onfr5 naq urkntba - onfr6